# Rails - generating .sqlite3-databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sqlite

My rails app. uses mysql database and I need to generate .sqlite3.databases. Is it possible to use activerecord and rails models for it?
We are trying now to use models namespaced by Remote:: module but by this way we can't start concurrent generators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your remote models, you want to connect to a separate database using #establish_connection:

```
# config/database.yml
remote_development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3

remote_production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: /usr/local/remote/myapp.sqlite3


# app/models/remote_model.rb
class RemoteModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "remote_#{Rails.env}"
  self.abstract_class = true
end


# app/models/remote_user.rb
class RemoteUser < RemoteModel
end
```

Note the abstract_class setter: this means the class in question doesn't have an underlying table: it's used for configuration purposes only.

Comment: I need to create different sqlite databases. Generation processes may be concurrent. I need dynamic database names...

Comment: establish_connection also accepts a Hash, thus you can say "RemoteModel.send(:establish_connection, :adapter => "sqlite3", :database => Rails.root + "tmp/#{Time.to_i}.sqlite3")